# Multi threading Concept in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: .net, multithreading, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a procedure, which takes some input in the form of an Array, which is being passed from a .NET Web Application.

IN PROCEDURE:
I open a cursor containing all data in the table, then fetching data from cursor row by row and apply validation rules on it.

For each row I need multiple hits to DB (almost containing nested queries); if data validation fails then I update `remarks` field in same table (by using an update query immediately), and if validation is successful then inserting/updating data in other table.

I tried it on 0.25 Million records, and I noticed that it takes more than one hour to process it.

I need to improve the performance of this Stored Procedure. Please let me know how to achieve this.

I have an idea about this.

**Making multiple sets of record (10 k in each set) and then process each set just like the way we use multi threading.**

Is this possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely, your procedure can be made faster by use of PL/SQL batch processing capabilities. To run code in parallel, look at DBMS_JOB and DBMS_SCHEDULER packages. Also, check if parts of your code can be speed up by Parallel Query and/or Parallel DML.
 Line by line is the slowest thing, especially if you used explicit cursor.

Comment: OK. Thanks for guidance. I am new to Oracle JOBS/SCHEDULER, Can you please provide me some useful links to get started in it ? 

Thanks in Advance

Comment: For dbms_job you can start with http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#ARPLS66558. For dbms_scheduler it is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235. <br> For any search in Oracle server docs, you can start with http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage and use search on top left.

Comment: The version of oracle is not specified in the question, be aware that the documentation links are for 11g release 2, things may work differently on your version.

Answer (score 3):

There is noting like multithreading in Oracle. If you really need to run something in background(parallel) you need either JOB or SCHEDULER_JOB. You can "theoretically" speedup your sequential(batch) processing by using:

- bulk/forall constructs
- "WHERE OF CURRENT" condition in UPDATE statement
- replacing INSERT/UPDATE with MERGE statement
- use "in memory" tables in joins - SQL type "TABLE OF <something>"
- use PARALLEL hint - in some complex SQL queries

Just keep in mind that "PL" and "SQL are two distinct "virtual" machines and context switches between them are(can be) slow.

Use of parallelism/multithreading  is common solution in the Java/.NET world. In Oracle this approach is not used to often.

Comment: The context switch itself [is not slow](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602); doing it thousands of times can be.